# Most important spec to look for on a GPU for scrypt mining (e.g. Litecoin)

Tags: litecoin, gpu, scrypt, mining-hardware, amd

By taking a look at all the current AMD cards comparison:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units

I was wondering if GFLOPS would be the best way to compare the raw power those cards would have for Litecoin mining.
In that case is single or double precision more important for the current mining software?

Also I'm aware that power consumption is another key factor.

Edit:

No answers so far...
A friend of mine who has been mining for a while thinks the number of shaders is the most important one. Still in the comparison chart above there are more specs that could be important I guess:

- Pixel pipelines
- Vertex shaders
- Texture mapping units
- Render output units

Still I think that they should all be reflected into the Processing Power GFLOPs, either single or double precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the important factors for scrypt in OpenCL are as follows

- GPU core clock rate
- Memory clock rate / memory bandwidth
- Memory bus width / channel
- Computation Units
- Processing Elements

You can check out in Programming Guide of AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing.

single or double precision of floating number does not matter. Either SHA-256 or scrypt is doing integer arithmetic operations.

Comment: That's correct, number of integer (as opposed to floating point) arithmetic operations per second is what matters most in mining. And ATI's chips tend to be better in that metric than NVidia's. Since they're cheaper as well, that's the reason you're generally not adviced to buy NVidia for mining: you'd get more hashes (i.e. money) with ATI for each kilowatt of power consumed.